# Pipe crashing at 1020 iterations

Tags: c, multithreading, fork, pipe

Well I'm programming in C, I was doing this

```
FILE *pipe;
pid_t child;
int fd[2];

child = fork();

if ( child == 0 )
{
 dup2(fd[2], STDOUT_FILENO);
 close(fd[0]);
 execl("func", "func", str_attr, NULL);

 exit(0);
}else
 {
  waitpid(child, NULL,0);
  pipe = fdopen(fd[0],"r");
  fscanf(pipe,"%s",buffer);
  fclose(pipe);
 }
```

When I try with more than 1019 cases, crash. I tried to debug but i don't see anything rare in my code. It seems that the pipe is broken when pass the 1020 iteration

Comment: What's the actual crash message?

Comment: Segmentation, I think because the pipe is broken and when the program do fscanf, crash

Comment: Can you show the full source code?

Comment: You might be reaching the limits of your session. `ulimit` can tell what your limits are.

Comment: Think I fixed it, I have reaching the limit of filedescriptors

Answer (score 0):

Think I fixed it, I have reaching the limit of filedescriptors –  user3358907